# Charts in the data explorer

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, graphs

I don't know whether the data explorer was created for SOFU, obviously if it wasn't this is impractical. Would it be possible to add an option to display the results as a chart?

Comment: +1 *totally* my vision is to have http://code.google.com/p/flot/ charts.

Comment: or http://code.google.com/apis/charttools/

Comment: or even http://g.raphaeljs.com/ , it is open source now and this would be a super welcome contribution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's some preliminary graphing support that waffles added that will be triggered on certain result sets. [Check out an example query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/58861) and click the Graph tab in the result pane to see a basic line graph of the results.

For more complex graphing purposes, using the added URL functionality that [ldolon mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118548/150235) is the way to go for now, but I imagine that the native graphing support will be extended in the future.

Answer (score 4):

URLs are now supported in the output data, so as @GragBray suggested you can use Google Chart API to create links to the charts. Check the following (simple and silly) example:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/58830/playground-how-many-upvotes-do-i-have-for-each-tag

Answer (score 3):

Actually, If there was a feature that let you add "Magic columns" with arbitrary URLs then you could use the http://code.google.com/apis/charttools/ to create charts and graphs.

Example:
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:60,40&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World