# How to get chart of stackoverflow data?

Tags: feature-request, data-analysis, graphs

I'd like to get a chart representing various SO data. Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: Have you checked out http://data.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 2):

Look through the blog, Jeff posts various charts every now and then.

Otherwise, take a look at data.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the only available chart you can get is for your and other users' reputation (AKA the reputation graph) from the user profile pages.

The most promising way to get this done is to complete the outstanding feature request to [add charting to SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54064/charts-in-the-data-explorer) (note: [SEDE is open-source](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer)!); otherwise, I think you're probably out of luck unless you have a specific case that would benefit everyone.