# Allow to create Magic Column with an arbitrary URL

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer, magic-columns

Currently data.SE supports two types of so called Magic Columns:

> If you alias an id column with as [Post Link] it will automatically
>   create a link in the result set to the parent site. Similarly if you
>   alias an id column with as [User Link] it will display a link to the
>   user page.

It would be helpful to have the ability to create the Magic Column with an arbitrary URL. This way we could create [links to charts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54064/158912), [links to edit suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85193/how-can-i-see-all-my-rejected-edits/104579#104579), links to any of the ["unlinked pages"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76566/list-of-unlinked-pages-on-stack-exchange-sites) (e.g. [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1732348/timeline), [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1732348/revisions), [flag weight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-weight/648313)) and so on.

These magic columns could be identified by an alias ending with " Link" (another option is " Url"), e.g. `[Chart Link]`, `[Suggestion Link]` etc. Where the data value in such column could be in 2 forms:

1. Plain URL, like "`https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/4000`" - this will display link as is.
2. URL with a title separated in some way, for example: "`Suggestion 4000|https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/4000`" or "`[Suggestion 4000](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/4000)`". Personally I prefer `|` as a separator.

Comment: Might as well also ask for [History Link] `http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1732348/revisions` and  [Timeline Link] as well `http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1732348/timeline`

Comment: @ConradFrix If this request got implemented, it would be very easy to add links you provided. Btw, thanks for the link to the "timeline" screen - nice hidden feature I wasn't aware of.

Comment: [Tag Link] too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is now implemented,

See: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/58786/a-demonstration-of-magic-links

We do a tiny amount of parsing on the links and optionally you can pipe separate a url `|` description pair.