# Data Explorer truncates links after 380 characters

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

During my experiments with [links to the charts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118548/158912) I noticed that the resulting links in Data Explorer are truncated after 380 characters.

Try the following query: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/58883/test-long-url

> SELECT 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p&chco=FF0000%2CFFFF00%7CFF8000%2C00FF00%7C00FF00%2C0000FF&chs=450x200&chd=t%3A122%2C42%2C17%2C10%2C8%2C7%2C7%2C7%2C7%2C6%2C6%2C6%2C6%2C5%2C5&chl=122%7C42%7C17%7C10%7C8%7C7%7C7%7C7%7C7%7C6%7C6%7C6%7C6%7C5%7C5&chdl=android%7Cjava%7Cstack-trace%7Cbroadcastreceiver%7Candroid-ndk%7Cuser-agent%7Candroid-webview%7Cwebview%7Cbackground%7Cmultithreading%7Candroid-source%7Csms%7Cadb12345678%7Csollections%7Cactivity|Chart'

The resulting url truncates at `%7Cmultithr` point, also link name (`Chart`) is not applied.

**UPDATE**

After deploy the truncation is still present. I've checked the `query.js` source and [found the following](http://code.google.com/r/tmslft-sede/source/browse/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Scripts/query.js?spec=svn39b3437985865073c03620d5104f63e7d195844c&r=39b3437985865073c03620d5104f63e7d195844c#891):

```js
function encodeColumn(s) {
    if (s != null && s.replace != null) {
        s = s.replace(/[\n\r]/g, " ")
              .replace(/&(?!\w+([;\s]|$))/g, "&amp;")
              .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
              .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
              .substring(0, 400);
        return s;
    } else {
        return s;
    }
}
```

I guess that `substring(0, 400)` should be removed or changed to something more democratic, e.g.: `substring(0, 8000)`.

Comment: And you think 380 characters is...not enough?

Comment: @jadarnel27 Well, it may not be enough for the links to Google Charts (check the linked feature-request for details). Of course there could be some behind-the-scenes reasons for the limit… Let's wait for devs reply.

Comment: Indeed, my mistake.  Good catch!

Comment: fixed and deployed

Comment: @waffles The link from my test query is still truncated at `multithr` part. Check my updated post: there is `substring(0, 400)` in `encodeColumn` function.

Comment: @Idolon can you try again

Comment: @waffles Ok, it's not truncated now, but `&` in the URL is replaced with `&amp` (shouldn't there be semicolon at the end?). [Check it here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/58897/test-amp-url-replace): this should create a link to `http://google.com/?hl=en&q=Test` but creates to `http://google.com/?hl=en&ampq=Test` instead.

Comment: @Idolon yeah, Tim is looking into it and possibly posting a related SO question

Comment: @waffles Thanks. It's almost 3am here so I guess I'll read Tim's question tomorrow morning ;) Just FYI: after last change it's also impossible to add `|` in the URL as `%7C` since it is replaced with `%257C` (vertical line symbol is used in Google Charts URLs). Updated [test query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/58897/test-amp-url-replace) accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, the `encodeColumn()` function was being called a little too early on values that ended up being autolinked. I've [patched the relevant code](http://code.google.com/r/tmslft-sede/source/detail?r=39b3437985865073c03620d5104f63e7d195844c), so hopefully this will be fixed whenever waffles next gets a chance to deploy.

Comment: did you yank latest from main prior to patching?

Comment: Yep, hot off the presses. Should be based off your most recent commit, as of ten or so hours ago I believe.

Comment: cool, feel free to fix any bugs you see, the data model has changed a bit. it is basically a mirror of gist.

Comment: Will do. And yeah, I glanced over the revisions and it's much, much better now.

Comment: @TimStone As I understand the issue is `substring(0, 400)` [at line 891](http://code.google.com/r/tmslft-sede/source/browse/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Scripts/query.js?spec=svn39b3437985865073c03620d5104f63e7d195844c&r=39b3437985865073c03620d5104f63e7d195844c#891)

Comment: @Idolon Yeah, another deploy is going out that should address this, give it a few minutes.

Comment: @TimStone Thanks for the fix - works like a charm now.

Comment: @Idolon Good stuff. Sorry for the delay; your specific problem was easy enough to resolve, but there was a more general issue of whether or not we should try and encode the URL for you (which caused double-encoding in your example).

Comment: @TimStone NP, I followed your progress in Mercury and was aware that encoding issue wasn't so simple to resolve.